# How to have a flex item that stretches based on text length (and having a second one fill the rest of the div)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

The following grips stretch based on the colmun number:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">right</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">left</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">right</div>
  </div>
  <!-- etc -->  
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/bdPPdx

How to do it so I have 2 flex items: one that stretches based on the width of the text and another that fills the rest of the div horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-auto` to stretch based on the width of the text and `col` to fill the rest of the div horizontally.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto">This will stretches based on the width of the text</div>
    <div class="col">This will fills the rest of the div horizontally</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b8f6s67/).